# MySQL JOIN values from another table based on (duplicate) values from original table within that table

Tags: mysql, database, row, multiple-columns

I encountered the following problem while trying to work with data from a network visualization.

I have two Tables, one containing the nodes in that network (called **Nodes**), and the other one the edges connecting them (called **edges**).

This is the **edges** table:

```
| Source| Target | ModularityClass |
|-------|--------|-----------------|
| UserA | UserB  | NULL            |
| UserA | UserC  | NULL            |
| UserC | UserD  | NULL            |
| UserC | UserB  | NULL            |
| UserE | UserB  | NULL            |
```

And this is the **nodes** table:

```
| Username| ModularityClass |
|---------|-----------------|
|  UserA  |       38        |
|  UserB  |       11        |
|  UserC  |       38        |
|  UserD  |       23        |
|  UserE  |       11        |
```

The **nodes** table has a `modularityClass` value that is assigned to at least 2 rows (Users).

What I want to do now is assigning the `modularityClass` value from the **nodes** table for rows having the same value (Users with the same `modularityClass` i.e. *duplicates*) to the corresponding row in the **edges** table which contains these both values (Users). The final table in this example should then look like this:

```
| Source| Target | ModularityClass |
|-------|--------|-----------------|
| UserA | UserB  | NULL            |
| UserA | UserC  |       38        |
| UserC | UserD  | NULL            |
| UserC | UserB  | NULL            |
| UserE | UserB  |       11        |
```

This would obviously lead to certain `NULL` values in the final table, but this is intended and not a problem.

So basically, I need to check another table for duplicate values (at least two) in a specific column, then get the values of these rows and compare them to two rows of the original table, and `JOIN` those onto the `modularityClass`row.

However, how would you do that?

Comment: Just to clarify your goal, do you need a query, or an update on the original `edges` table?

Comment: @Shidersz Generally, I'd like to update the original `edges` table, however if the query works, I can just join the `edges` table afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join with `Nodes` twice, once for `Source` and once for `Target`. Make the them  `LEFT JOIN` so you get `NULL` when you don't have all the matches.

```
SELECT e.Source, e.Target, n2.ModularityClass
FROM edges AS e
LEFT JOIN nodes AS n1 ON n1.username = e.Source
LEFT JOIN nodes AS n2 ON n2.username = e.Target AND n1.ModularityClass = n2.ModularityClass
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e7R8S3E2uPUMi9VtVFbPeK/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can left join the nodes for each user and if the modularity class matches.

```
UPDATE edges e
       LEFT JOIN nodes ns
                 ON ns.username = e.source
       LEFT JOIN nodes nt
                 ON nt.username = e.target
                    AND nt.modularityclass = ns.modularityclass
       SET e.modularityclass = nt.modularityclass;
```

But I recommend not to physically store values, that can be compute from others. That's a recipe for inconsistencies. Each time you change the values in `nodes` the modularity class in `edges` might get wrong.

Better drop the `modularityclass` from `edges` and use a view, that shows the edges with the modularity class.

```
ALTER TABLE edges
            DROP COLUMN modularityclass;

CREATE VIEW edges_with_modularityclass
AS
SELECT e.source,
       e.target,
       nt.modularityclass
       FROM edges e
            LEFT JOIN nodes ns
                      ON ns.username = e.source
            LEFT JOIN nodes nt
                      ON nt.username = e.target
                         AND nt.modularityclass = ns.modularityclass;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e1aae988da44733b1e6eb74cab2a9cd)

Comment: thank you for your answer and the remarks - as I just need it for specific one-time analyses I thought that might be sufficient, but I'll keep that in mind for the future!